# How can I check that the length of a list of custom data types in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension, nested-lists, haskell-platform

I'm making a simple sudoku program that only utilises a 9 x 9 grid. To that end, I have a function to check it is 9 x 9 and also checks to make sure the inputted values are `Just Num`'s.

Here's the closest solution I've come to, I'm thinking the issue is in the pattern match I think (correct me if I'm wrong), this is because it compiles but has the logical error of returning False not True when given a perfectly fine test case. Anyways, here's the code dump :D

```
type Cell = Maybe Int
type Row  = [Cell]

data Sudoku = Sudoku [Row]
 deriving ( Show, Eq )

rows :: Sudoku -> [Row]
rows (Sudoku ms) = ms

isSudoku :: Sudoku -> Bool
isSudoku (Sudoku [[cs]]) = length [cs] == 9 && length cs == 9
isSudoku (Sudoku _)      = False
```

Many thanks in advance for any advice given!

Comment: Hint: `length [cs]` is always `1`.

Comment: And `[[cs]]` is always a list containing a list containing a single value; it doesn't match an arbitrary nested list.

Comment: `[cs]` is a list of length1, and `[[cs]]` is a light of length 1 whose single element is a list of length 1. Don't use `[[cs]]` as a pattern. Use `cs`, and do the appropriate checks later on. You can use `all predicate list` to check some condition on all the elements.

Comment: Record syntax would simplify this as well: `data Sudoku = Sudoku { rows: [Row] }` defines your data type and the `rows` accessor at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[x]` as a pattern will only match a singleton list (list with exactly one element in it).

To perform the nested lists check, do

```
isSudokuList cs  =  length cs == ...    &&
                      and [length c == ... | c <- cs]
```

You will have to tweak it to fit your types of course.

You could also define

```
niner [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i] = True
.......
```

and use *it*.